# Cakephp 3.0 or > on Azure?

Tags: php, azure, cakephp

Is it possible to run Cake 3.0 or higher on Azure Web Apps? I have an app running locally on a 3+ version but when I installed CakePHP on my Azure web app it's running 2.5.1.

I **feel** like it's just a matter of uploading all of the newer files and the db created for the 3.0 version but scared there is some kind of write access the new cake will need thus preventing it from running and burning a ton of my time.

I started learning PHP 3 weeks ago so calling me a newb is probably an insult to newbs.

[This article](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/appendices/3-0-migration-guide.html#new-orm) tells answered most of my original questions regarding this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to deploy `CakePHP > 3.0` applications to Azure Web Apps. But we need to some preactions to make the application to run. Generally, you can try to following steps:

1. Create an empty Azure Web Apps, and enable `Composer` extension, and also you can enable `Visual Studio Online` for easy script modifications and command running. Refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-php-mysql-deploy-use-git/#enable-composer-automation-with-the-composer-extension for more.
2. Create a file named `web.config` with the content at http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html#iis7-windows-hosts in the root directory of your application.
3. Add the `inlt` extension in PHP runtime on Azure. Add a folder named `ext` in your root directory, create a file `ext.ini` in this folder with the content:
   `extension=php_intl.dll`. Add an App Setting to your Web App with the key `PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR` and value `d:\home\site\wwwroot\ext`. You also can do this step leverage `Visual Studio Online` extension after deployment. Refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-php-configure/ for details.
4. Set up the development environment of your Azure Web Apps, deploy your CakePHP application to Azure via Git. Refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-php-mysql-deploy-use-git/#set-up-the-development-environment for details.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. I'm just a little out of my league on what's been asked of me. It sure helps to get answers like this.