# How to enable apache rewrite_module programmatically in a shared server?

Tags: php, apache, cakephp, mod-rewrite, azure-web-app-service

How do enable the PHP rewrite_module for a shared server like godaddy?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow :) This is not enough information for us to figure out what your issue is. [How to ask a good question.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Azure Web Apps uses IIS to host your PHP applications. If your original rewrite_module configurations are written in `.htaccess` file, you need to convert the rewrite_module into a `web.config` which is an IIS configuration file. You can leverage [this online tool](http://htaccesstowebconfig.com/) to convert `.htaccess` to `web.config` content, and insert into a `web.config` file in the root directory of your PHP application.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                // your convert content
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

And you can refer to [Cakephp 3.0 or > on Azure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36431233/cakephp-3-0-or-on-azure/36442065#36442065) for the steps of deploy a cakephp application to Azure Web Apps.